# How to request image from URL (with popup) - Android studio

Tags: android, popup, imageview

i have implemented this pop up , its a simple one, it opens randomnly every time i enter to the listview item.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_serviciosp);



    final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openpopup);
    btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                    = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


            Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
            btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    popupWindow.dismiss();

                }
            });

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);


        }


    });

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random random = new Random();
            int x = random.nextInt(7) + 1;
            if (!userClicked && x == 1 || x == 3 || x == 5)
                btnOpenPopup.performClick();

        }

    }, 100);



}
```

}

Now, what i need to do is this, i need to open a imageview from URL inside the popup windows, i tried everything i could find in google, i found a library called "Picasso" and the only thing i need to add to the oncreate method is only this 2 lines to show an image from the web

```
 ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.popup);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("IMAGEURL").into(iv);
```

I want to load that image from the internet inside the pop up i made, but when i try to add it inside the oncreate method my app crash

I also added permision in android manifest for internet, but i cant get this to work

My logcat is empty and do not show anything.

here is the picasso library : http://square.github.io/picasso/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imageview instantiation should happen only AFTER you have a refernce for that pop-up window view, the app crashes probabley because picasso is trying to inject that image to a null object reference.
Try and add those lines AFTER - 

    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

also add the lines like so - 

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.popup);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("IMAGEURL").into(iv);

The reason for the change is that the imageview you are trying to get is inside the popupView view.

Comment: Man, thanks so much, i have been working on this like 8 hs from now !  thanks so much !